# Plot with pandas and logy

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

How can i make the plot y axis print 1,10,100,1000 and not 10² and so on.
See the figure how i don't want it

Is it possible to do so? If i run the plot without logy=True i get the ints on y axis but i need to plot with logistic. I have no idea how i can fix this. Do i have to use matplotlib outside of pandas to get it done?

Sorry for very bad english..

[image: How i don't want it]

Comment: So, `formatter=ScalarFormatter()`; `formatter.set_scientific(False)`; `ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)` and maybe also `ax.yaxis.set_minor_formatter(formatter)`.   If you don't write a minimal example, it is hard to know the exact names to make it work in your situation.  Note that pandas plotting is just an interface to matplotlib.

Comment: The only thing you need to know in addition to the duplicate is that you get the axes `ax` via `ax = df.plot(...)`.

Comment: Ahh thanks johanC..